# Center Bootstrap column with multiple DIV tags

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I want to show an image, and next to it (on the same line) some text.
This is easy enough, but I also want this content (image and text), to be centered in a bootstrap grid so it retains its properties on all devices and continues to scale/collapse.

[image]

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="img.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using offsets, but can't get it to work. Should I wrap the image and content in spans? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try [text-center](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) and [center-block](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)?

Comment: i want to use the bootstrap grid so it collapses properly on mobiles...

Comment: If you only have 1 item centered you don't need a grid.

Comment: that's right, but i have two items - an image and some text.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a wrapper div for the image and the text, and then align it to the center.

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="img.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h1>CONTENT</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: this is close, but how would i set a width for the image?
if i set a fixed width inline, it over rules the img-responsive.

Comment: You should use percentages. For example: width: 60%;

Comment: I have made some improvements. Can you tell me if this works better: http://www.bootply.com/JCazfsp1Pt

Answer (score 1):

I think that your mistake is using *row-fluid* instead of *containter-fluid*. The latter will center the row within.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"
        <img src="img.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

You could also make your own custom class and apply *margin: 0 auto;* to the element.